# How to stop control creation inside a repeater based on a condtition?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the control i want to be created only if the condition is true. How do I do that using say the "Visible" attribute or something easy like that?

```
 <p><%# (GetAnswer(Eval("AnsQID"))) != 1 ? (Eval("AText")) : ""%></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" Text='<%# GetAnswer(Eval("AnsQID")) != 1 ? (Eval("AText")) : "" %>' Visible='<%# YourMethodHere() %>' />
```

Comment: ^-^ now that solves my problem ! been searching the whole internet for this , you are a life saver ! thanks a lot